# Sql Search query within range of data stored in groups or categories

Tags: sql-server

i need to store data about activity houses for youngsters which should be stores like 15-19, 12-20, 10-23, 10-19 etc.

and then i want to be able to search that which one or more of them matched the incoming query.

for example some one want to search for activity houses that are suitbale for 20 so it should return houses that have 12-20 and 10-23.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clearer description of what "suitable" means would help.  You should not be storing numeric values as strings, however.

Comment: I would advice you to include some code you have tried into your question. It will increase the chances of receiving help and reduce the chances to have your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your table with 2 columns representing the range allowed, e.g., `minCapacity` and `maxCapacity`.

Then you can structure your query using BETWEEN. e.g.

```
... WHERE @request BETWEEN minCapacity AND maxCapacity.
```